# SimpleXML на PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

В общем, есть код:

```
$xmlDoc = simplexml_load_file($xmlPath . 'result.xml');

foreach($xmlDoc->attributes() as $a => $b)
    echo $a . ' = ' . $b . '<br />';

    if ($a == 'clientOrderId'){
        $orderId = $b;
    }
    if ($a == 'status'){
        $status = $b;
    }
    if ($a == 'error'){
        $error = $b;
    }
    if ($a == 'techMessage'){
        $techMessage = $b;
        $_SESSION['techMessage'] = $techMessage;
    }
}

$_SESSION['status'] = $status;
$_SESSION['error'] = $error;
$_SESSION['error_text'] = $res['error_text'];

echo '<pre>';
echo print_r($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
```

но при выводе получаю:

```
clientOrderId = 1493813331128
status = 3
error = 44
processedDT = 2017-05-03T15:08:52.832+03:00
Array
(
    [__flash] => Array
        (
        )

    [__id] => 128
    [storeCard] => success
    [status] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => 3
    )

    [error] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
         [0] => 44
    )

    [error_text] => 
)
```

В общем, мне нужно только значение, а берется целый объект почему-то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы брать чисто значение нужно привести объект к строке:

```
$status = (string) $b;
```

Comment: ништяк работает спасибо.

Comment: @Moonwolf45 А голосовать "за" и принимать как правильный ответ кто будет?